# How to authenticate to Gmail using IMAP through OAuth2 (Python)

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-imap

I'm trying to write a local application that uses IMAP to talk to a user's Gmail account, with authentication via OAuth 2.0. It works fine when I don't request the user's email address in the consent screen and use the email I already know is his/hers (for the tests). But now I need to get their email address and use it for the IMAP XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.

The problem is: if I request the user's email address, suddenly the IMAP authentication doesn't work anymore. It gives me a Invalid Credentials error.

I already tried asking for the email in the scopes list but using a hardcoded email (just like in the tests) and it does not work. It seems that as soon as I add the "email" scope, it ceases to generate a valid token.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give some more details? e.g. the code that does work, the code that does, a copy of the exact error message etc?

Comment: Never mind... I found another way to solve to do what I was trying to do. Thank you, anyway.